# How to allow resizable Grid Columns to automatically stretch to remaining space in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF XAML I cannot seem to get the grid columns to take up the remaining space before a `GridSplitter` element. It's strange as the vertical one is working and seems to have the exact same set up. I have tried a number of things including using `Width="*"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the column definitions and the left panel `Grid` itself, but nothing seems to allow it to stretch to the first `GridSplitter`.

###### Here is an example of what is happening when using the `GridSplitter` elements to manually resize:

[image: Example of WPF Grid resizing issue]

###### And here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Left Panel -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="LightSlateGray">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="4"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Left Panel | Top -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10 10 10 10">Test</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        
        <!-- Left Panel Grid Splitter -->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" ></GridSplitter>

        <!-- Left Panel | Bottom -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Test</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Horizontal Grid Splitter -->
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Width="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" ></GridSplitter>

    <!-- Right Panel -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Test</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

All I really want is for the first `Grid.Column` that holds the left panel to resize itself and it's content to cover the remaining space between the left of the window, and the `GridSplitter`.

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: [How to: Resize Columns with a GridSplitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-resize-columns-with-a-gridsplitter?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Horizontal Grid Splitter" needs `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`. Actually any value other than `Right` - which appears to be the default for `GridSplitter` - works fine.

You would have the same issue in your inner (vertical) splitter if you set `VerticalAlignment` to `Bottom`, but this apparently is not the default value.

WPF layout never ceases to keep us on our toes.

Comment: Amazing thank you! I tried so many different things but this worked. Definitely seems like a weird "fix" but at least it works haha! Thanks again :)